# Is it possible to store unique_ptr in a QList of QPairs?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, stl, unique-ptr

To avoid a lot of unnecessary copying I'm trying to store unique_ptr's in a list of pairs. I'm using a simple class Test which takes a QString;

I'm using VS2013 with Qt5.4

```
using std::unique_ptr;

QList<QPair<unique_ptr<Test>, unique_ptr<Test>>> list;

auto a = std::make_unique<Test>("a");
auto b = std::make_unique<Test>("b");

// First make a pair
auto pair = qMakePair(std::move(a), std::move(b));      // Fails
// Error C2280 - attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Because of failure I tried:

```
QList<std::pair<unique_ptr<Test>, unique_ptr<Test>>> list;
auto pair = std::make_pair(std::move(a), std::move(b)); // Succes
list.append(std::move(pair)); // Fails
// Error C2280 - attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Because of failure I changed completely to STL containters:

```
std::list<std::pair<unique_ptr<Test>, unique_ptr<Test>>> list;
auto pair = make_pair(std::move(a), std::move(b)); // Succes
list.push_back(std::move(pair)); // Succes
```

This works. Is my conclusion correct that these Qt containers don't support move semantics and I have to use STL instead?

Comment: Note that `std::list` is rarely a good idea.  `QList` is more similar to `std::vector` than `std::list`.  This does not answer your question.

Comment: That deleted function would be the copy-constructor (which the QContainers all need because of copy-on-write semantics),

Comment: I found an answer at [link](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2013-July/007776.html). You can't use std::unique_ptr in Qt containers. Qt containers require the type to have a default constructor, a copy constructor, and an assignment operator, and you can't copy a std::unique_ptr.

Comment: @Yakk: I do not think QList is like std::vector, are you sure it use consecutive memory and not chained pointers?

Comment: @adr You maybe right.  I recsll it being a skip list?  With lg n random access.

Comment: @Yakk: After a deeper reading, you seem right. seem like a deque. +1

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique_ptr` is not copyable, so nope for Qt containers.

Qt containers where created way before std::move (or even std::string) became a thing.

Maybe there will be better support in Qt6. It is poised to break a few things to integrate better with modern C++.

OTOH, you might as well use the std-containers if they work for you, unless you had some specific use case in mind?